# Postincrementation operator in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I had to write a program that handle this main code:(not allowed to change it)

```
list<int> iv;

  iv["john"] = 23;

  int ia = iv["john"]++;
  int ib = iv["john"];

  cout << ia << " " << ib << endl; // prints 23 24
  try{
  cout << iv["jack"] << endl;   // should throw an exception
  }catch(list<int>::Uninitialized&)
  {
    cout << "Uninitialized map element!" << endl;
  };
```

Here is my code:

```
#ifndef EXAM_H
#define EXAM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class TYPE>
class list
{
private:
struct node
{
  TYPE value;
  string index;
  bool isInit;
  node *next;
};
node *head;
node *current;
public:
  class Cref
  {
    friend class list;
    list& s;
    string position;
    Cref (list& ss, string pos): s(ss), position(pos) {};
  public:
    operator TYPE() const
    {
      return s.read(position);
    }
    Cref& operator = (TYPE val)
    {
      s.write(position,val);
      return *this;
    };
    Cref& operator = (const Cref& ref)
    {
      return operator= ((TYPE)ref);
    };
  };
  class Uninitialized{};
  list ()
  {
    cout << "constructor\n";
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
  }

  ~list ()
  {
    while (head)
      {
        node *t = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = t;
      };
  }

  TYPE read (string ind) const
    {
      cout << "read\n";
      node *t = head;
      while(t)
      {
        if(t->index == ind && t->isInit == true)    return t->value;
        else t = t->next;
      }
      throw Uninitialized();
    }  

void write (string ind, TYPE value_)
{
 cout << "write\n";
 node *t = new node;
 t->next = head;
 head = t;
 head->value = value_;
 head->index = ind;
 head->isInit = true;
}  

TYPE operator[] (string ind) const
{
 cout << "read\n";
      node *t = head;
      while(t)
      {
        if(t->index == ind && t->isInit == true)    return t->value;
        else t = t->next;
      }
      throw Uninitialized();
}

Cref operator[] (string ind)
{
  return Cref(*this, ind);
}

};
#endif
```

Everything works great, but only when I comment out postincrementation operation in main program

```
int ia = iv["john"]++;
```

As you can see I have a struct node where I put all variables and I want to increment value by one in node where the key is "john". Is there any way to implement operator++ for this code ?
I am not allowed to use std::map.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but `using namespace std;` is a very bad idea in the global namespace - especially if you declare your own class called `list`.

Comment: I don't see you fixing this anytime soon without a rework of how your `operator TYPE()` operators work. As-written there is no chance of incrementing the underlying data as there is no reference to it. Everything is by-val copies.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you. I will write another version using vectors

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to your problem is defining the array subscript operators as

```
const TYPE& operator[](string ind) const;
TYPE& operator[](string ind);
```

In this way, you do not have to bother a single bit about the `operator++`: Since `iv["John"]` returns a reference to `int`, `iv["John"]++` will call the `int` post-increment operator which is built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have already tried this solution, but compiler do not distinguish between reading and writing and still using non-const version. So I had to build proxy class Cref that helps to distinguish.
I have also already find a solution to operator++ problem.
This operation had to be from Cref level. I created

```
Cref& operator++ (int val)
    {
      s.increment(position,val);
      return *this;
    };
```

And increment function in main class body as follows:

```
void increment (string ind, int value_)
{
 cout << "increment\n";
 node *t = head;
 while(t)
 {
    if(t->index == ind && t->isInit == true)    t->value = t->value + 1;
    t = t->next;
 }
}
```

That fully solved my problem.